# Get email notification for using 'sudo' by a specific user

Tags: sudo, users, email, visudo

I have a server set-up and I let somebody that I trust with a little bit of `sudo` access have it. However, I also want an email anytime that they use `sudo`.

I know that I can use `Defaults    mail_always` to get an email anytime ANYONE tries to use `sudo`, but I have a cron-job for OwnCloud that runs every 30 minutes and requires a `sudo -u www-data` at the beginning of it. Obviously, I don't want an email every 30-minutes.

How can I always get an email just for 1 specific user?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After some experimentation, I found the answer.  To set options such as `mail_always` or `root_pw` for specific users, you can add a line like this to your `sudoers` file after opening with `visudo`:

```
Defaults:USER_NAME mail_always
```

Just make sure that this line is inserted near the top, where the other `Defaults` options are. In addition, if you want to specify the recipient of the emails:

```
Defaults mailto="youremail@domain.tld"
```

Comment: also, ensure your host is actually able to send email (:

Comment: I don't see how this helps you - `sudo /bin/bash` will be tracked, but commands passed to the `root` `bash` won't be. Similarly, `sudo vi foo`, followed by `:!rm /etc/passwd` will not be logged.  Reread `man sudoers`. You can set up sudo so that it will allow a single command, without a password.

Comment: @Waltinator I know how to set-up `sudo` for single commands, or just a few commands. I've already done that. I just also wanted an email anytime one of those commands was used with `sudo` by that specific user. This solved my problem by achieving exactly what my question asked.

Comment: i  put sudo in front of everything all the time. sudo sensors, sudo free, sudo pwd, sudo cd, I want the computer to know who's boss, you know?